# Assign domains to Docker container (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx, docker-compose, containers

I have a Laravel application running as Docker container. This is the docker-compose.yaml file

```
version: "3.7"

networks:
    wise-sso-network:
        driver: bridge

services:
    app:
        build:
            # args:
            #     user: root
            #     uid: 0
            context: ./
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: laravel8-php-fpm-80
        container_name: wise-sso-app
        restart: unless-stopped
        working_dir: /var/www/html/wise.sso
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html/wise.sso
        networks:
            - wise-sso-network

    db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        container_name: wise-sso-mysql
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - 3310:3306
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
            SERVICE_TAGS: dev
            SERVICE_NAME: mysql
        volumes:
            # - ./docker-compose/mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
            - wise-sso-datavolume:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - wise-sso-network

    nginx:
        image: nginx:alpine
        container_name: wise-sso-nginx
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - "8097:80"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html/wise.sso
            - ./docker-compose/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
        networks:
            - wise-sso-network

volumes:
    wise-sso-datavolume:
```

And this is the nginx conf file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sso.wise-portal.com;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html/wise.sso/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

I've added the subdomain to /etc/hosts and I'm able to access the site either via http://localhost:8097 or http://sso.wise-portal.com:8097. But, I'd like to remove the port from the URL and access it directly via http://sso.wise-portal.com.

I'd like to add that since I have multiple containers, I would not be able to default to the port to 80.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

just change 8097 to 80 in docker-compose nginx service

```
nginx:
        image: nginx:alpine
        container_name: wise-sso-nginx
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - "80:80"
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, but I have other containers and I can't default it to 80.

Comment: @LCYoong Sorry I don't think you can do that. You can't use the same port on your local machine and you can't add port in the etc/hosts file either. So I think it is impossible